# Why is the left side of Euler's formula not equal to the right when I plug in numbers?

Tags: complex-numbers

I am struggling to understand Euler’s equation and when I insert numbers, I can’t get the left side to equal the right side.  Searching Stack Exchange and other web sources, I am not finding an answer.  Here is the situation:

Given the formula

$$e^{ia} = \cos(a)+i \sin(a)$$

If I assign values:

$i = 2$ ;
$a = 0.087\, \mathrm{radians}$ (same as five degrees)

$cos(a) = 0.996$ ;
$sin(a) = 0.087$ ;
$i*sin(a) = 0.174$.

the right-hand side equals $1.171$
the left-hand side equals $1.191$

and of course, those two are not equal.

Why the two sides of this equation not equal?

Comment: I see the error immediately: You "assign" $i=2$. This $i$ is not a variable, but it's the imaginary unit. That's your problem. So unfortunately, I think you have not really grasped what there numbers and equations mean. When you write an expression like $e^{iz}$, it's a function of only one variable $z$.

Comment: $i$ is a constant, you cannot assign to it the value you want.

Comment: $i$ isn't an arbitrary value, it's the imaginary unit

Comment: I just want to help you see that $i$ is not a variable here ... If it were a variable, we could set $i=0$ and we would get
$$
e^0 = \cos a + 0
$$
which just means $1=\cos a$. This equation is certainly not true for all values of $a$. So we have a contradiction immediately. I hope you understand what I'm trying to point out here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $i$ is not a variable. It is the imaginary unit.

Comment: This has already been pointed out in the comments.